# filter an array of two different types without the use of casting?

Tags: typescript

How to filter an array of tow different types and get the targeted type, I used casing but I caused issues further in the code and I cannot use function predicated since I haven't isolated the value yet any idea how to this ?

the error I am getting on el.user is

> Property 'user' does not exist on type 'UserType' | 'AdminType'

```js
export type UserType = { user: string; data: string}
export type AdminType = { admin: string; data: string }


const usersAndAdminsArr =[{ admin: '2312'; data: 'blabla' }, { admin: '33123'; data: 'blabla' }, { user: '111'; data: '' }] 
// get the array of filter users only (exclude admins)

const userType = usersAndAdminsArr.filter((el) => el.user === selected.user);

 const isUser = (item: any): item is UserType => {
      return item.user !== undefined;
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually applying your type guard. You need to first filter out non `UserType` objects, and *then* filter the users.

```js
usersAndAdminsArr.filter(isUser).filter((userObj) => userObj.user === selected.user)
```

See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCqBnYUAqzUC8cA3nAK5ZQBccGMUAlgHYDmA3HACYCGM3NdRqwC+AKFCRYCfHACCnALbM8KOEVLdFzAfWbsuvfrV2s4Y0aIDGEJnXKUMspp3lLbsqFDUBtDVqY0AOQATADMAIzBgQA0BnxBAEYANtzJ3IFmsX5uQaERYTFxRoFpaRnCWfbYQeG1hTzxcIHlALpwogD0HXAswPAwABao3J7ciHAQAGZwkwxJMNhVUBgTTEnjABSglklknMP+GACUFqJJfbTA55YLnGpLjs6uzI6e3sEtp9a28AwYmIsiBsGAsFDRuExEEcaCDgAo4H90JQVIQAHwkURwLFwKB9MhQJgI0EAOgoiwAhAQiGRnMBZkxgJw2KJhMyLN87GTcDJqQ4nC5Dh4oMTZvNsMD-pQjiK5gsoBsNlyAPIJABWRzU6OVatJlDUVMu11uuuwR2ZQA) and make sure you also take a look at [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)